# Separating spaces at the end of a string

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the Codecademy JavaScript tutorials and they keep separating the space at the end of the string before a variable.

For example:

```
nameString("Hello, nice to meet you," + " " + name);
```

Is this a common practice? I usually just tack that last space on.

```
nameString("Hello, nice to meet you, " + name);
```

Comment: Maybe they are just doing that to emphasize how string additions can be made?

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly fine.

Comment: FWIW, you're doing the way I do it. That first way seems unduly tedious to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I guess it's a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are exactly alike in their end result and the usage of one of the other may come down to a stylistic preference. However, there is a possible benefit for using the former method (adding a " " explicitly) over the latter (having the " " as a part of the first string.

Say that in the future, you decide to localize your greetings to the client and maintain a JS Object that contains a mapping from language to localized greeting since your application has grown in influence. For example,

```
greetings = {
    "English": "Hello, nice to meet you", 
    "Spanish": "Hola, un placer conocerte"
    ...
}
```

Now, here in the Object, we can safely not worry about adding the space character to the end of each translation if we use the former method. In this scenario, the former method not only saves us a potentially large number of bytes but also, in my opinion, makes the code more semantic. Usage would proceed something like this:

```
nameString(greetings[language] + " " + name);
```

If it's something you are certain that you won't be switching out for a variable in the future, perhaps the latter method is the easiest. Nevertheless, the most important principle is to attempt to be consistent with the stylistic choices that you make.

Comment: It does affect convenience, but it's not all that *inconvenient* to just separate the space when you switch out the string for a variable. Thanks for the answer, though.